# The usage of "ice somebody"

Tags: american-english

I saw it in an American TV series *Supernatural* many times. The characters say "ice the devil", "ice them".

I guess they mean kill (or freeze, put into a seal?) the devil but have not found similar usage of it. Is it just a word specific to this TV series? Or slang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ***[to ice](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/h2ovtii)*** also means:

5. to attack physically.
   (a) to murder, to kill

> 1953  [US]    ‘Death Row’ in D. Wepman et al. Life (1976) 118: *In making my exit, I iced a cop.*

…..

> 2021  [US]    T. Pluck Boy from County Hell 177: *[T]heir order was to ice Desmarteaux.*

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So does this word related to kill because people may use ice to preserve dead body?

Comment: I think the metaphors refers to the fact that when you are dead you turn cold.